# Multisession parallelism with a shared stderr redirect

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rparallel

I am trying to run R code with multisession parallelism such that all the error messages redirect to the same file. However, the `sink()` cannot be created.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
f <- function(){
  withr::with_message_sink("messages.txt", Sys.sleep(10))
}
clusterCall(cl = cl, fun = f)

## Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :
##   2 nodes produced errors; first error: Cannot establish message sink when another sink is active.
## Calls: clusterCall -> checkForRemoteErrors
## Execution halted
```

---

## **Edit**

Given some of the responses, I should elaborate on the purpose of this post. I am developing [drake](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake), an R package with multiple parallel backends. Today, I implemented a new [`hook` argument](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/blob/master/R/make.R#L34) to [`make()`](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/blob/master/R/make.R#L183), which just [wraps individual parallel jobs](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/blob/master/R/build.R#L12) in a [function of the user's choice](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/blob/master/R/make.R#L188). What I am really looking for is a `hook` that silences the console regardless of parallel backend. Backends in the current development version include

- `parallel::mclapply()`
- `parallel::parLapply()`
- `base::lapply()` (via `parLapply()` for one job)
- `make -j` with a proper `Makefile`
- `future::sequential`
- `future::multicore`
- `future::multisession`
- [`future.batchtools` backends listed here](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.batchtools/#choosing-batchtools-backend)

I thought I found a `hook` that worked for stderr.

```
hook <- function(){
  withr::with_message_sink("messages.txt", Sys.sleep(10))
}
```

However, `withr::with_message_sink()` does not let me sink multiple workers to the same file for the `parLapply()` or `future::multisession` backends.

Comment: I think I have had a similar need/problem/solution, but I need a bit more info. By 'multi-session' are we talking across multiple active-sessions on the same server, or simply multiple pid's? What's the main goal? Like in my case I needed to  run multiple large jobs in parallel, and if any iteration throws an error I have a tryCatch log the error, but I don't stall anything out purposefully..just skip over

Comment: Good call. Please see my edit. My own needs are unusual. In your case, [development drake](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake) might help. I just implemented a new [`diagnose()` function](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/issues/114) that retrieves verbose error information on failed targets, including the error message and call stack.

Comment: Together, functions `drake::failed()` and `drake::diagnose()` remove the strict need for ordinary error messages printed to the console. I am planning a CRAN update in November with these new features.

Comment: my gnarly brute-force suppression method lol:
`shh <- function(...){
  invisible(
    suppressWarnings(
      suppressPackageStartupMessages(
        suppressMessages(
          ...
        )
      )
    )
  )
}`

Comment: Good idea. Works for `parLapply`, but `drake::make(drake::workflow(x = stop()), parallelism = "Makefile", jobs = 2, hook = ssh, verbose = FALSE)` is unfortunately not silent.

Comment: I checked out the repo... Not sure if it's useful, but I put a script I use in the issues docket for your use if you so choose. Good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use sink?:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
clusterApply(cl, seq_along(cl), function(i) workerID <<- i)


f <- function(){
  outtxt <- paste(workerID, "messages.txt", sep="_")
  print(outtxt)
  sink(outtxt)
  Sys.sleep(10)
  sink()
}
clusterCall(cl = cl, fun = f)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: I did use `outfile` at one point, but I was [persuaded otherwise](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/171#issuecomment-339442682). Please see my edit.

Comment: could you just use sink?

Comment: For whatever reason, that did not work when I tried it before. But since you brought it up, I tried `make(..., hook = message_sink_hook)` with the [silencer hook here](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/blob/master/R/hooks.R#L32), and it seems to work everywhere.